# Como obtener todos los alumnos que no adeuden cuotas al dia de la fecha

Tags: mysql

Buenas tardes tengo el siguiente problema con una consulta sql :
Necesito obtener el nombre y el apellido de aquellos alumnos que se encuentren al dia con los pagos de las cuotas de un colegio.

Mi consulta es esta pero no funciona

```
SELECT CONCAT(pe.apellido," ",pe.nombre)AS alumno,pe.numero_documento,cu.* FROM persona AS pe
INNER JOIN alumno AS cl ON pe.id_persona=cl.id_persona
INNER JOIN inscripcion AS pr ON cl.id_persona=pr.id_persona
INNER JOIN cuota AS cu ON pr.id_inscripcion=cu.id_inscripcion
INNER JOIN estado_cuota AS ec ON cu.id_estado_cuota=ec.id_estado_cuota
GROUP BY pe.id_persona,cu.id_cuota,pr.id_inscripcion
HAVING (cu.id_estado_cuota=1 and (cu.id_estado_cuota!=3 AND cu.id_estado_cuota!=2)) AND cu.vencimiento < now()
ORDER BY pr.id_inscripcion ASC,cu.id_cuota ASC
```

Para ello tengo la tabla persona , la tabla alumno , la tabla inscripcion , la tabla cuota y la tabla cuota

```
id_estado_cuota=1 PAGADA
id_estado_cuota=2 IMPAGA
id_Estado_cuota=3 EN MORA
```

LA TABLA CUOTA CONTIENE LOS SIGUIENTES CAMPOS

```
id_cuota int 
nro_cuota int
valor_cuota decimal
vencimiento date
id_estado_cuota int (clave foránea)
id_inscripcion int (clave foranea)
```

¿ Por favor podrían darme una mano ?

Muchas gracias . Saludos

Comment: necesitaríamos la estructura de la tabla Cuotas. Porque con tu consulta actual no hay como diferenciar que alguna de las cuotas esté pagada y el resto no

Comment: como añado la estructura ?

Comment: en la pregunta explícanos cuáles son las columnas que tiene esa tabla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, primero que todo, deberías entender la lógica para encontrar las cuotas que no estén al día (que supongo son aquellas cuya fecha de vencimiento es anterior a hoy, y cuyo estado no es "Pagada"). Esta sería la consulta para encontrar aquellas cuotas:

```
SELECT *
FROM Cuota 
WHERE vencimiento < NOW()
AND id_estado_cuota <> 1;
```

Ahora podemos mezclar esta consulta con el resto de las tablas para encontrar los datos que necesitas:

```
SELECT  CONCAT(pe.apellido," ",pe.nombre) AS alumno,
        pe.numero_documento
FROM persona AS pe
INNER JOIN alumno AS cl 
    ON pe.id_persona = cl.id_persona
INNER JOIN inscripcion AS pr 
    ON cl.id_persona = pr.id_persona
WHERE pr.id_inscripcion NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT id_inscripcion 
                                FROM Cuota 
                                WHERE vencimiento < NOW()
                                AND id_estado_cuota <> 1);
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Lamak , la verdad me habia hecho un lio el having en mi consultas. saludos

Comment: @franciscocastillo Ningún problema. Como regla general, se usa `HAVING` cuando realmente necesitas agrupar información; algo que en este caso no era necesario.